# Netty - write to a channel until it is writable

Tags: java, networking, netty, nio

According to [this](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-twitter-meetup-netty/slides.html#9.0), to determine the **Writability** of the channel we can call `channel.isWritable` and then write to the channel if it was **Writable**.

i.e :

```
private void writeIfPossible(Channel channel) {
    while(needsToWrite && channel.isWritable()) {
        channel.writeAndFlush(createMessage());
    }
}
```

but, what about this :

```
private void writeIfPossible(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    Channel channel = ctx.channel();
    channel.eventLoop().execute(() -> {
        while (needsToWrite && channel.isWritable()) {
            ctx.write(createMessage(), ctx.voidPromise());
        }
        ctx.flush();
    });
}
```

Is this correct? I mean, does `channel.write` (or `ctx.write`) have any effect on the writability of the channel? Or we must call `channel.flush` after each write?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data is only really written out to the underlying socket if you call flush(). So if you never call flush() it will isWritable() will continue to return false until you may see an OOME. Whenever you call flush() is up to you and depends on how much you want to buffer before trying to flush etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Mr. Maurer.

I end up with this :

```
public void sendMessages(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, RecyclableArrayList messages) {
    Channel channel = ctx.channel();
    channel.eventLoop().execute(() -> {
        int i = 0;
        while (channel.isActive() && channel.isWritable() && i < messages.size()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5 && i < messages.size(); j++, i++) {
                ctx.write(messages.get(i), ctx.voidPromise());
            }
            ctx.flush();
        }
        if (i < messages.size()) {
            messages.subList(0, i).clear();
            storeMessages(ctx.name(), messages);
        } else {
            messages.recycle();
        }
    });
}
```

I'd appreciate any other recommendations.